# Vue2 + Typescript. Missing field in object if assign Prop to object

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

If i use TypeScript version 4.1 and i have component like this.

```
@Component
export default class Test extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;

  private testObj={
    msg: this.msg,
    test: 123
  }

  created(){
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.testObj)));
  }
}
```

In console i will see

```
{
msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"
test: 123
}
```

But if i change version to typescript 4.3 with same code. I will see only

```
{
test: 123
}
```

**msg** - prop was removed

Question: why?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is coming from a breaking change in Typescript 4.3
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html
useDefineForClassFields now defaults to true.

I added useDefineForClassFields:false in my tsconfig.json and it solved the issue.